# SDL rendering is slow and stuttering

Tags: c++, performance, sdl

Im relatively new to both c++ and working with SDL but I managed to create a small 2d library for vectors and Im trying to use it to give some rectangles some speed and acceleration however the animation runs so slow.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the amount of calls i'm making but I can't figure it out.

```
while (true) {

    screen.clear();

    if (particleCreate == false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {

            pParticles[i].position.setX(screen.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2);
            pParticles[i].position.setY(screen.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
            pParticles[i].velocity.setLen((rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX) * 15.0);
            pParticles[i].velocity.setAng((rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX) * 360.0);
            pParticles[i].gravity.setY(0.5);

        }

        particleCreate = true;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {

        pParticles[i].update();

        screen.drawRect(pParticles[i].position.getX(),pParticles[i].position.getY(), 5, 5);

    }

    if (screen.wait() == false) {
        cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
        screen.close();
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how much code I should put in here but this is the main loop.

EDIT: I should mention that Im using the SDL_RenderDrawRect to draw the rectangle and SDL_RenderClear to clear the screen.

Comment: How many particles do you have? How many fps you're getting?

Comment: 20 for testing purposes. It also seems that some of the particles are flashing I mean I get that they being redrawn but some of the others dont flash like that.. I'm just very confused because it seems like simple code

Comment: I'm not sure if SDL is meant to draw fast animations. I have some experience with fast 2D on Windows, and GDI is the fastest in that particular case. You can also obtain good results by emulating 2D with a 3D rendering API such as OpenGL. This may be useful for your SDL stuff: http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/animating-sprites-with-sdl/

Comment: Okay, Im basically just doing basic stuff to learn programming math so I don't need anything fancy but it would be nice if it ran properly. Im not sure how to use OpenGL or GDI? Are they similar to setup like SDL? I think I also heard that some people use OpenGL within SDL? In general very confused about my options when it comes to this lol.

Comment: Maybe start with that gamedevgeek link I sent. If that one runs smooth, you are likely doing something wrong...

Comment: I cant get it to compile I think it might be an old version of SDL. Either way I fixed it sort of by drawing to a texture instead.. I guess the render functions are just slow by default since I didnt change the code otherwise. Thanks for the help.